# Angular JS - Number Validation If TextField Is Not Empty

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, decimal

I have a textfield on my angular js form for the Sale Price of an item. This field is not required, however I want it to be validated for valid number/decimal input > 0 if the user puts a value in the field. Any invalid input should force the field to revert back to 0.00M decimal.

I've tried a few different variations on my basic validNumber directive but I can't get it work. My directive works fine if I wanted the value to always be required for input.

Here's the directive I'm using now for the RetailPrice which is required. I've chopped out the code I added, since it wasn't working anyways.

```
app.directive('validNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var regex = /^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/;
            var validator = function (value) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('validNumber', regex.test(value));
                return value;
            };
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label class="span5"> Username:<span style="color: red" ng-show="manageupdateuser.loginname.$error.required" >*</span></label>
            <div class="span6">
                <input class="span12" type="text" name="loginname" ng-model="oldusername" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]+$/" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="25" required>
                <span style="color: red" ng-show="manageupdateuser.loginname.$error.minlength">Allow minimum 2 characters.</span>
                <span style="color: red" ng-show="manageupdateuser.loginname.$error.maxlength">Allow maximum 25 characters.</span>
                <span style="color: red" ng-show="manageupdateuser.loginname.$error.pattern">Any other symbol are not allow.</span>
            </div>
```

This is demo for only allow a-z and A-z or minimum and maximum length...
also digit or ohter special char are not allow...
You not specified which type of validation you need...

Comment: Thanks for fast response sir. This would work great for alphanumeric, however I'm looking for numeric/decimal validation for value.

Comment: you only change ng-pattern ....write a regular expression for your need..it's work directly

Comment: ng-pattern="/^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/"                    add this validation it's work fine